# Microsoft graph API - MFA status per user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to check the status of MFA by a user in my organization.

From what I have found at Google I saw that I need to request this URL https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails.

In version v1.0 this request returns this error:

`{'error': {'code': 'BadRequest', 'message': "Resource not found for the segment 'credentialUserRegistrationDetails'.", 'innerError': {'date': '2022-09-14T06:54:05', 'request-id': '9ee64e6d-6a0a-4c38-a316-451290c5989d', 'client-request-id': '9ee64e6d-6a0a-4c38-a316-451290c5989d'}}}`

In version beta it returns an empty list:

`{'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails', 'value': []}`

The beta version is not supported and seems as not working as well.

There is a way to get the status in v1.0?

Answer (score 0):

This is not available for version v1 ,
[image]

you have to try in beta only.
I tried from my end this is working fine with API- https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails
[image]

Comment: could you please also provide the timestamp and request id for your API call for beta ?

Comment: I don't have it any more..
Microsoft is telling to not use the beta version in production, what should I do?

Comment: When I'm trying what you have done I'm getting an empty list.

Comment: You means when you tried in beta version (non-production ) , you got empty list ,right?

Comment: This is weird that you are getting , Just for curiosity , could you please also try once in PowerShell - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.reports/get-mgreportcredentialuserregistrationdetail?view=graph-powershell-beta